# how to get intermidiate results in ipython parallel processing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

my work is to deal with lots of xmls; to get faster results i want to use ipython's parallel processing; below is my sample code. in that i am just finding the number of elements of xml/xsd with `celementTree` module.

```
>>> from IPython.parallel import Client
>>> import os
>>> c = Client()
>>> c.ids
>>> lview = c.load_balanced_view()
>>> lview.block =True
>>> def return_len(xml_filepath):
        import xml.etree.cElementTree as cElementTree
        tree = cElementTree.parse(xml_filepath)
        my_count=0
        file_result=[]
        cdict={}
        for elem in tree.getiterator():
            cdict[my_count]={}
            if elem.tag:
                cdict[my_count]['tag']=elem.tag
            if elem.text:
                cdict[my_count]['text']=(elem.text).strip()
            if elem.attrib.items():
                cdict[my_count]['xmlattb']={}
                for key, value in elem.attrib.items():
                    cdict[my_count]['xmlattb'][key]=value
            if list(elem):
                cdict[my_count]['xmlinfo']=len(list(elem))
            if elem.tail:
                cdict[my_count]['tail']=elem.tail.strip()
            my_count+=1
        output=xml_filepath.split('\\')[-1],len(cdict)
        return output
        ## return cdict
>>> def get_dir_list(target_dir, *extensions):
        """
        This function will filter out the files from given dir based on their extensions
        """
        my_paths=[]
        for top, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
            for nm in files:
                fileStats = os.stat(os.path.join(top, nm))
                if nm.split('.')[-1] in extensions:
                    my_paths.append(top+'\\'+nm)
        return my_paths
>>> r=lview.map_async(return_len,get_dir_list('C:\\test_folder','xsd','xml'))
```

to get the final result i have to do
`>>> r.get()` by this i will get result when process will complete 
 my question is am i able to get the intermediate results while they are getting finished; 
for example if i have applied my work to a folder which contains 1000 xmls/xsds files then can i get results immediately when that particular files has been processed. like `1st file is done--> show its result... 2nd file is done---> show its result........ 1000th file is done--> show its result` not like current work as above; `wait till final file get finished` then it will show complete result of all those 1000 files.

 also to deal with import/namespace error i have defined `import` inside of `return_len` function; is there any better way to deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  AsyncMapResult (the type returned by map_async) are iterable immediately,
and the items yielded by the iteration are the same as the list ultimately produced by `r.get()`.  So after you do:

```
amr = lview.map_async(return_len, get_dir_list('C:\\test_folder','xsd','xml'))
```

You can do:

```
for r in amr:
    print r
```

or keep the index with enumerate

```
for i,r in enumerate(amr):
    print i, r
```

or perform reductions with the `reduce` builtin:

```
summary_result = reduce(myfunc, amr)
```

All of these will iterate through your results *as they arrive*.  If you don't care about the ordering and the time for each task is significantly varied, you can pass `map_async(...,ordered=False)`.  If you do this, when you iterate through the AMR, you will get individual results on a first-come-first-serve basis, rather than preserving the submission order.

There's a bit more info [in the ipython docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.1/parallel/asyncresult.html#map-results-are-iterable).

> also to deal with import/namespace error i have defined import inside of return_len function; is there any better way to deal with that?

Yes and no.  There are a few ways to set up the engine namespace, such as using modules, the `@parallel.require("module")` decorator, or simply performing the import explicitly with `%px import xml.etree.cElementTree as cElementTree`, each of which has benefits in certain scenarios.  But I often find putting imports in the function to be the easiest way, and with the least surprises.

Comment: `@minrk and all ipython dev team`: You all guys have done great work.. seriously.. . according to me ipython is one of the best app/program/lib by python community.

Comment: @minrk Is there a non-blocking way to iterate through the results that are already done, and then only iterate on the other results as they come in?

Comment: If you do `map_async(...ordered=False)`, results will be yielded as they arrive, regardless of submission order.

Comment: Is there any way to properly import a django project class to run this async tasks?